# How to make a DataGrid cell template that is larger than the cell but fully visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In the .Net 4.0 WPF Datagrid, the edit mode of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` pops up the `ComboBox` drop-down in a size that is not dependent on the size of the cell containing the data.

I am building a template for a cell that is somewhat like a combobox, but has features like multi-select, other controls as collaborating neighbors, etc. My editor is working nicely, except for one issue.

I've been trying to figure out how to make the editor appear in front of the `DataGridCell` that is being edited, and not limited to the current size of that cell, so that the control can be large enough to present content and behaviors nicely to the user. This is similar to what the drop-down of the combobox cell does in WPF data grid.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBoxes` use [`Popups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx), you could put your control in one (presumably only when editing -> Put one in the [`CellEditingTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate.aspx)).

Comment: H.B. - Thanks, this looks very promising. I thought it would have to be something simple that I was missing.